# reCaptcha with custom language

Tags: captcha

I have reCaptcha (Google recaptcha) for my site by using module recaptcha

It's working good but I need to change language to my local language.

I've read language code

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language

But I don't know how to do it in the module

Thanks

[image: This is what I want]

Comment: [try the patch in here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1177498)